# Где достать статистику с заболеваниями онкологии в городах РФ?

Tags: машинное-обучение, поиск-данных

Может кто-то может мне подсказать, где я могу взять статистику  по городам по заболеваниям онкологии с выборкой в несколько лет, которые я могу скачать в формате xlsx или csv. Все обрыскал есть только по регионам

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не о программировании.

Comment: @Эникейщик
А где я могу задать  такой вопрос, ведь мне нужны эти для данные для реализации машинного обучения

Comment: я считаю, что вопрос уместный, автор спрашивает источник для решение it задачи, вопросы из разряда "литература по сетям" более абстрактные. А тут вопрос про dataScience и ML, он конкретный и является частью it

Comment: @Эникейщик Ну тэг машинное обучение тут ведь есть, поиск данных для задач ML вполне себе относится к ML, мне кажется.